# Access QFiledialog programmatically

Tags: qt, gui-testing, qttest

I am trying to do the system testing in QT created application. I have encountered the below problem.
Open menu action in my application triggers a QFileDialog. I have handle(pointer) for the same. But i am not sure how to select the required file and trigger the open action.

Below things i have tried:

```
fileDial->setDirectory("xxxx");
fileDial->selectFile(xxx");
fileDial->fileSelected("xxxx");
fileDial->selectNameFilter("xxx");
```

and note that i haven't get any action for the

```
fileDial->findChildren<QAction*>().
```

Comment: To the close voters: This is perfectly clear. What were you thinking?

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639613/how-to-close-qfiledialog-programmatically#comment40063834_25639613

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QFileDialog` is just a wrapper on a system dialog. That's why it's useless to search for any `QActions` there. Instead if you run you program in Windows you can use WIN API to deal with the dialog.

Here is a simple example where some text is placed in the file name control and Open button is clicked:

```
#define WAIT(A) while (!(A)) {}
HWND dialogHandle, button, edit, combo, comboEx;
WAIT(dialogHandle = FindWindow(NULL, L"Open"));
WAIT(button = FindWindowEx(dialogHandle, NULL, L"Button", L"&Open"));
WAIT(comboEx = FindWindowEx(dialogHandle, comboEx, L"ComboBoxEx32", NULL));
WAIT(combo = FindWindowEx(comboEx, combo, L"ComboBox", NULL));
WAIT(edit = FindWindowEx(combo, NULL, L"Edit", NULL));

char text[] = "arc.h";
SendMessageA(edit, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM) text);

SendMessage(button, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need multiplatform(win/mac) solution

Comment: @anbu-velusamy If you use static methods of QFileDialog it uses native system dialogs of OS. In this case it's impossible have a multiplatform solution, because it's not implemented in Qt. You can code solutions for both win and mac. But if you create QFileDialog with "show" it will be a usual Qt dialog and you can  control it.

Comment: Thank you. Is there way to access in Mac?

Comment: I can't help you with Mac. You can create another specific question  for this.